# how to insert new variable in (*args,**kwargs) section?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, decorator

i want to make a decoration method to assign the variable which the function would use but wouldn't be deliver by itself.

for example add new variable y in lambda r,i wrote code in this way but didn't work.

```
r = lambda x:x+y

def foo(func):
    def wrapped(*args,**kwargs):
        y = 3
        return func(y=y,*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapped

r = foo(r)
print(r(444))
```

this wouldn't work too

```
r = lambda x:x+y

def foo(func):
    def wrapped(*args,**kwargs):
        y = 3
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapped

r = foo(r)
print(r(444))
```

Comment: `r` can accept just one argument, you're passing too many args.

Answer (score 6):

`kwargs` is a casual python dict type, so you can just set the value of the `y` key to be 3

```
r = lambda x, y=0:x+y

def foo(func):
    def wrapped(*args,**kwargs):
        print type(kwargs) #  will output <type 'dict'>
        kwargs['y'] = 3
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

In [Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python) this is explained in details.

Comment: This is not going to work and will raise : `TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y'`

Comment: r takes only two arguments where as you can pass variable number of positional and keyword arguments to the argument of `func`.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that the function `r` can accept only one argument, you need to change its definition to accept more args:

```
r = lambda x, y=0, *args, **kwargs: x + y

def foo(func):
    def wrapped(*args,**kwargs):
        y = 3
        return func(y=y, *args,**kwargs)
    return wrapped

r = foo(r)
print(r(444))
#447
```